# CORS error when accessing the services thorough the StackSaga Admin server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway, stacksaga

I tried to access my order-service through the StackSaga admin server. The request goes through the Spring Cloud API gateway as well. but unfortunately, all the time I am getting a `CORS error` at the browser console.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to access the stacksaga event-store API through the Spring Cloud API gateway you have to allow the Origins for the admin server. for instance, if the admin server running on the port `localhost:4444` you have to allow the Origins for all the endpoints that go through the API gateway that contains `stacksaga/` (because all the event-store API endpoints are started with `stacksaga`) like below in the `yaml` file (or .properties file).

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/*/stacksaga/**]':
            allowedOrigins:
              - "http://localhost:44441"
            allowedMethods: "*"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

This is actually not related to StackSaga framework. read [this document](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gateway/2.2.0.M1/#_cors_configuration) for more information.